# Deleting a record from a table that has been modified by a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables namely "ab" and "eff" in mysql database.
My requirement is that when there is a status update in "ab",I need to move that particular record to "eff" and delete the old record in "ab".

I have written an  after update trigger to successfully move the record from "ab" to "eff".But I am unable to delete the record from "ab".

The error thrown is as follows:Can't update table 'ab' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Please suggest a method by which I can delete the record from "ab".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: U can write an update trigger for other table, if you insert value, delete the value from other table.

Comment: @VinuBibin Please don't use abbrevations like "U". Take the time to write "you" instead. Not everyone is familiar with them, especially non-native-speakers.

Comment: I have written an after insert trigger on the eff table,but the same error is thrown again

Comment: mysql will not allow you to do as @VinuBibin suggests. You could either soft delete from ab by setting a flag and then delete later or log all the records written from ab in your trigger and delete later.

Comment: @P.Salmon-Are these the only options possible or are there any other methods by which I can delete the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete the rows from the same table on which you implement the trigger. Because on insert MySQL locks the table and can't delete the rows because delete needs locking so its a deadlock situation, that's why MySQL would not allow this.

You need to handle this out of the trigger scope by marking with a flag for delete.